# When i load a applet in page and then go in offline mode and restart browser, i get noclassfound exception, for applet

Tags: java, applet

When i load a applet in page and then go in offline mode(by disabling network connection) and restart browser, i get noclassfound exception, for applet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank your guys for the answer but i got the solution, it is registered as a bug in the java and still not solved

Answer (score 0):

The question is quite unclear but still...

---

Perhaps it means that applet class, as a resource, was not cashed. But to be more sure I need to look at its html start web page and js (if it uses it)